# Import / Export Global WooCommerce Attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have an old website with 100+ Terms and Taxonomies stored in Global WooCommerce Store.

In my latest developed website, I want to migrate them all at once.
I do not want products from that website. I just want the Attributes stored from: `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes`

I have checked this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/17338) raised by a user like me.
I also did a google search a lot. Either some are providing paid plugins or some are not in line with my need. I have tried WP ALL Import / Export plugin. But it has a paid solution for WooCommerce Import and Export.

Is there any simple way I can export and import global attributes?

Comment: Try this free [WooCommerce Product import export plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) by WebToffee

Comment: I do not want to import products. I want Global Attributes only to the destination website.